# Functional equations of curves

Tags: math, equation, curve

I am looking for the way to express particular (see the picture below) curves using functional equations.

What's important (supposing the chart's size is 1x1 - actually it doesn't matter in the final result):

- obviously the shape - as shown in the picture;
- there should be three solutions to f(x) = x: 
   x=0, x close to or equal 0.5 and x=1;
- it would be really nice, if both of the arcs are scalable - as shown in the left example (the lower arc is more significant than the upper one).

[image: Curves examples]

I've done some research, but nothing seemed to match my needs. I tried trigonometric and sigmoid functions too, they turned out to be quite close to what I want. I'd be grateful for any hints or even solutions.

Comment: Have you looked at splines? Are the only points requiring interpolation 0,0.5 and 1?

Comment: Might be a question for http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: No, I haven't; actually I've never heard of them before - I don't have any serious knowledge of higher mathematics. Thanks for pointing a possible direction. What should I start with?
The points 0, 0.5 and 1 should be the only mutual points of the curve and f(x) = x. And additionally the (0.5,0.5) point should be the "crossing" point.

Comment: And thanks, Hot Licks, I've never hear of that site;)

Comment: Look at *cumulative distribution functions* or the *logistic equation*.

Comment: You tried sigmoids  you say - what in particular made them not suitable for your purpose?

Comment: Actually they are suitable, especially the logistic function, but I can't manage to fully take control over their shape. I wanted to look for additional solutions as well.

Comment: I was suggested it as well, I'll surely take a closer look at it, although it seems to be a bit complicated at a first glance. I am not sure whether it will be suitable for fast calculations.

Answer (score 2):

I beleive I've found a functional form that should suit your requirements, using a linear base (y=x) with two trigonometric adjustments. By adjusting the two parameters you should be able to reach any shape you desire. The constraints that f(x)=x for x=0,1,0.5 will always be satisfied. An increase in 'a' causes the two sides to bulge out (the left one down and the right one up), a value of 'b' other than zero will create an asymmetry between the two bulges.

```
y = x - a*sin(2*pi*x) - b*cos(4*pi*x) + b
```

In the example below I've chosen a to be 0.1 and b to be 0.015.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that looks pretty nice!